# LDAP Kerberos authentication on linux

Tags: linux, openldap, kerberos

I have configured my RHEL linux machine to be authenticated against active directory without being joining it to domain, using nss-pam-ldapd pam_ldap samba-winbind openldap-devel krb5-devel.
I am able to login on linux machines using active directory accounts, but I am not sure if the kerberos is being used during authentication, because I dont see the TGT in linux machine's local cache, but when I use "kinit username" and then check with klist I do see the TGT.
I am little confused, on how to confirm if the kerberos is being used or not.

Thanks,
Subodh.

Comment: You could run tcpdump/tshark on the RHEL host console and see if any kerberos connections go on while you log on in another window. I suspect you are logging on via LDAP, though

Comment: Hi, Thanks, 
I did check that with tcpdump -I eth1 port 88 and I get below response.
16:16:11.668583 IP MyLinuxBox.46509 > MyWindowsDomainController.kerberos:  v5
16:16:11.669810 IP MyWindowsDomainController.kerberos > MyLinuxBox.46509:
I think its using kerberos. :-)